# Equivalent condition of $A/I\cong A/J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $I(A)$ be the set of all ideals of $A$.

We define equivalent relation on $I(A)$ by $I\sim J\iff A/I\cong A/J$.

(Remark: We note $A/I\cong A/J$ means ring isomorphic **not** $A$-algebra isomorphic.)

For example, $A=k[x,y], I=(x), J=(y)$ then $I\neq J$ and $I\sim J. $

Can we state equivalent condition of $I\sim J$ in other words?

Comment: It is sufficient that there be an automorphism of $A$ mapping $I$ to $J$, but this is not necessary: for example, if $A=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, then the ideals $I=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ and $J=2\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\{0\}$ are equivalent, but they aren't even isomorphic as subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I changed my title. And your second comment is very interesting.

Comment: You can obviously drop the last factor of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the example. Don't know why I put it in...